# how should I draw Custom button on Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I want to draw custom button on Navigation bar.

Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"DontWorryAboutThis" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(method:)];
[barButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animage.png"]];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButton];
```

Comment: If you want back button, then you should not set leftBarButtonItem. If you want leftBarButtonItem, then you have no back button.

Answer (score 5):

simple

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: customButton];
```

will work

so something like that:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animage.png"]];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: button];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:customItem];
```

Cheers,
Krzysztof Zabłocki

Comment: and how can i add image to this custom button :)

Comment: and where to add this custom button means in which method... In ViewDidLoad() method.....

Comment: you could add it in viewDidLoad

Comment: sure, because you change left button ( left button is usually back button ), change right one [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:customItem];

Answer (score 0):

```
      UIBarButtonItem *btn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btnPressed)];
      [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:btn];
```

Comment: It would help if you provided the OP some context for the code block provided e.g. where it should go etc or links to documentation.